# Changing two states in child and parent component at the same time onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I have two components, the parent one below where I pass in this prop

```
changeState={() => this.functionName(index)}

functionName = (index) => () => {
  this.setState({ activeTab: index })
}
```

I then have the child component where i declare the prop and call the function

```
onClick={changeState}
```

This works as intended and changes the state in the parent component. The problem I have is at the same time I also want to have another onClick to change another state at the same time in the child component.

I have put both in a function and call the function with one `onClick` but only one is called... the other `onClick` I have is

```
this.toggle

toggle = () => {
  this.setState({
    collapsed: !this.state.collapsed,
  });
}
```

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible? Or is the fact that i'm calling two separate `setState` causing it to re-render before the other gets called?

Comment: You should add your JSX, a paste bin or a code pen. Without context it is hard to help you. Plus, your problem is not reproducible, thus not helping the community as much as it could.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) in the child component.

Your approach may have weird side effects, what with the parent refreshing and the child too at the same-ish time.

However, you should be able to add a callback as 2nd argument to `setState`, as in:

```
toggle = () => {
  this.setState({
    collapsed: !this.state.collapsed,
  }, changeState);
}
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work. It will call `changeState` but the toggle now does not work

Comment: could you provide some JSX?